# Keras, best way to save state when optimizing

Tags: python, keras

I was just wondering what is the best way to save the state of a model while it it optimizing.  I want to do this so I can run it for a while, save it, and come back to it some time later.  I know there is a function to save the weights and another function to save the model as JSON.  During learning I would need to save both the weights and the parameters of the model.  This includes parameters like the momentum and learning rate.  Is there a way to save both the model and weights in the same file.  I read that it is not considered good practice to use pickle.  Also would the momentums for the graident decent be included with the models JSON or in the weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a tar archive containing the weights and the architecture, as well as a pickle file containing the optimizer state returned by `model.optimizer.get_state()`.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'get_state'`

Comment: @MatthewKleinsmith: The API may have changed since I wrote this.

Comment: Yeah, it happens. My comment was purely informational.

Comment: @MatthewKleinsmith Mine too :)

Comment: @nbro feel free to

Answer (score 6):

```
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
del model  # deletes the existing model

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

> You can use model.save(filepath) to save a Keras model into a single
>   HDF5 file which will contain:
>
> - the architecture of the model, allowing to re-create the model
> - the weights of the model
> - the training configuration (loss, optimizer)
> - the state of the optimizer, allowing to resume training exactly where you left off.
>
> You can then use keras.models.load_model(filepath) to reinstantiate your model. load_model will also take care of compiling the model using the saved training configuration (unless the model was never compiled in the first place).

Keras FAQ: [How can I save a Keras model?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)