# Save and load weights and optimiser state for retraining

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I wanna save the model and load it with the optimizer state for retraining. I was able to save model weights as a `.h5` file and but have no luck with optimizer state. Please help me

Comment: Why do you think your optimizer state is not saved?

Comment: refer to this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43460788/13273054)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save the model using `model.save()` as `'h5'` object it stores optimizer state as well as all the other information required to restart the training procedure.
Code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
x = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,32))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, (1000,))
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
def scheduler(epoch, lr):
  if epoch < 1:
    return lr
  else:
    return lr * tf.math.exp(-0.1)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler, verbose = 1)
_ = model.fit(x= x, y = y, epochs = 25, validation_split=0.2, verbose = 1, callbacks=[callback])
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/25

Epoch 00001: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to 0.0010000000474974513.
25/25 [==============================] - 1s 24ms/step - loss: 0.6894 - accuracy: 0.5690 - val_loss: 0.6883 - val_accuracy: 0.5300
Epoch 2/25

Epoch 00002: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00090483745, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6853 - accuracy: 0.5378 - val_loss: 0.6843 - val_accuracy: 0.5650
Epoch 3/25

Epoch 00003: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.0008187308, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6798 - accuracy: 0.5327 - val_loss: 0.6917 - val_accuracy: 0.5350
Epoch 4/25

Epoch 00004: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.0007408183, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6733 - accuracy: 0.5744 - val_loss: 0.6848 - val_accuracy: 0.5550
Epoch 5/25

Epoch 00005: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.0006703201, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6679 - accuracy: 0.6259 - val_loss: 0.6847 - val_accuracy: 0.5450
Epoch 6/25

Epoch 00006: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00060653075, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6613 - accuracy: 0.6176 - val_loss: 0.6890 - val_accuracy: 0.5450
Epoch 7/25

Epoch 00007: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00054881175, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6660 - accuracy: 0.6037 - val_loss: 0.6862 - val_accuracy: 0.5600
Epoch 8/25

Epoch 00008: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.0004965854, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6635 - accuracy: 0.6162 - val_loss: 0.6886 - val_accuracy: 0.5600
Epoch 9/25

Epoch 00009: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00044932903, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6637 - accuracy: 0.5869 - val_loss: 0.6865 - val_accuracy: 0.5550
Epoch 10/25

Epoch 00010: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.0004065697, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6583 - accuracy: 0.6218 - val_loss: 0.6883 - val_accuracy: 0.5700
Epoch 11/25

Epoch 00011: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.0003678795, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6573 - accuracy: 0.5991 - val_loss: 0.6871 - val_accuracy: 0.5600
Epoch 12/25

Epoch 00012: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00033287113, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6497 - accuracy: 0.6228 - val_loss: 0.6876 - val_accuracy: 0.5650
Epoch 13/25

Epoch 00013: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00030119426, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6425 - accuracy: 0.6586 - val_loss: 0.6877 - val_accuracy: 0.5500
Epoch 14/25

Epoch 00014: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00027253185, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6424 - accuracy: 0.6579 - val_loss: 0.6878 - val_accuracy: 0.5650
Epoch 15/25

Epoch 00015: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00024659702, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6517 - accuracy: 0.6442 - val_loss: 0.6875 - val_accuracy: 0.5750
Epoch 16/25

Epoch 00016: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.0002231302, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6401 - accuracy: 0.6753 - val_loss: 0.6886 - val_accuracy: 0.5650
Epoch 17/25

Epoch 00017: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00020189656, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6388 - accuracy: 0.6553 - val_loss: 0.6879 - val_accuracy: 0.5650
Epoch 18/25

Epoch 00018: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00018268357, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6441 - accuracy: 0.6505 - val_loss: 0.6889 - val_accuracy: 0.5650
Epoch 19/25

Epoch 00019: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00016529893, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6427 - accuracy: 0.6533 - val_loss: 0.6880 - val_accuracy: 0.5650
Epoch 20/25

Epoch 00020: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00014956866, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6434 - accuracy: 0.6330 - val_loss: 0.6886 - val_accuracy: 0.5650
Epoch 21/25

Epoch 00021: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00013533531, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6279 - accuracy: 0.7061 - val_loss: 0.6880 - val_accuracy: 0.5600
Epoch 22/25

Epoch 00022: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.00012245646, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6368 - accuracy: 0.6492 - val_loss: 0.6883 - val_accuracy: 0.5700
Epoch 23/25

Epoch 00023: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.000110803194, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6385 - accuracy: 0.6558 - val_loss: 0.6886 - val_accuracy: 0.5650
Epoch 24/25

Epoch 00024: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(0.000100258876, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6323 - accuracy: 0.6689 - val_loss: 0.6884 - val_accuracy: 0.5600
Epoch 25/25

Epoch 00025: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to tf.Tensor(9.0717986e-05, shape=(), dtype=float32).
25/25 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6387 - accuracy: 0.6513 - val_loss: 0.6880 - val_accuracy: 0.5700
```

Saving & loading the model and checking lr of the loaded model:

```
model.save('mymodel.h5')
model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/mymodel.h5')
model1.optimizer.learning_rate
```

Output:

```
<tf.Variable 'learning_rate:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=9.0717986e-05>
```

As you can see above the final value of lr in output logs matches with lr value of loaded model.
The only thing you need to remember while restarting the model is provide a value for `initial_epoch` argument in `model.fit()` so all the values which depend on epoch value for their calculations eg(lr scheduler in the above case) are calculated correctly.