# How to load a TensorFlow model to retrain it without the optimizer states being reset?

Tags: tensorflow

When retraining a model by loading a TensorFlow model, the initial validation losses are well above the values at the end of the previous training due to the optimizer states being reset when loading the model due to its compilation. After several searches, I still don't understand how to continue training without having this problem. How do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to think about saving state of a learning scheduler, state of an optimizer and check if you seed globally random state.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Keras to save your model, this will be saved and loaded automatically:

From [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/saving/load_model)

```
tf.keras.saving.load_model(
    filepath, custom_objects=None, compile=True, safe_mode=True, **kwargs
)
```

The parameter that controls this on loading is `compile=True`.

You can also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37128886/keras-best-way-to-save-state-when-optimizing#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20model.save%20%28filepath%29%20to%20save%20a,to%20resume%20training%20exactly%20where%20you%20left%20off.)